# How to append some text to a variable in makefile?

Tags: shell, make, variable

I have a Makefile. Somewhere in the makefile there is a variable defined:

```
FOO=hello
```

Later on I need to append some text to `FOO`'s content. I tried it like this:

```
FOO=$(FOO)_world
```

I suggested that `echo $(FOO)` would output `hello_world`. Instead I get an error:

```
*** Recursive variable 'FOO' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
```

Using the `+=` operator is no option, because this would add a space in between.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need the `:=` in place of the recursive `=`:

```
FOO := hello
FOO := $(FOO)_world
$(info FOO=$(FOO))
```

hello_world

Answer (score 8):

I would say the makefile [`addsuffix`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-addsuffix-591) function is what you are looking for, thus in your case for example:

```
FOO := hello
FOO := $(addsuffix _world,$(FOO))
```

However @user218374 was right too and his solution works as well, in this case, but I am pretty sure you might be happy to have a look at these built-in expansion functions relating also to lists of file names!